# OIDC response_mode= form_post

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, implicit, form-post

I am implementing the response_mode=form_post and I would like to know what are the possible response_types for this mode.

I read in some places that it supports response_type=code, response_type=id_token.
(Login only cases). When access_token is returned, with type id_token token ,can we use form_post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any response type used with the `form_post` response mode. [The specification](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-multiple-response-types-1_0.html) defines default response modes that should be used with the given response types, but the spec for `form_post` does not limit its use to only some `response_type` cases.

Still, that should not make any difference for your implementation. You should just take the form returned by the authorization server and submit it, like you would any other HTML form on a page. So it doesn't matter for you what is in the form, and the action URL should be in the form anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

response_mode controls how the tokens are delivered to the client, if you use response_mode=form_post then it is done via an auto submitted **form-post** generated by the Identity provider. IF you don't provide it, you will get the tokens via the **query string**.
There are no more alterantives what I know of.

basically, response_mode defines how the tokens (ID/Access/refresh) are delivered to your client.

According to the spec [here](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html):

it says:

This specification defines the Form Post Response Mode, which is described with its response_mode parameter value:

> In this mode, Authorization Response parameters are encoded as HTML
> form values that are auto-submitted in the User Agent, and thus are
> transmitted via the HTTP POST method to the Client, with the result
> parameters being encoded in the body using the
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded format. The action attribute of the
> form MUST be the Client's Redirection URI. The method of the form
> attribute MUST be POST. Because the Authorization Response is intended
> to be used only once, the Authorization Server MUST instruct the User
> Agent (and any intermediaries) not to store or reuse the content of
> the response.
>
> Any technique supported by the User Agent MAY be used to cause the
> submission of the form, and any form content necessary to support this
> MAY be included, such as submit controls and client-side scripting
> commands. However, the Client MUST be able to process the message
> without regard for the mechanism by which the form submission was
> initiated.

https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html

Comment: You can also get tokens in the fragment part of the URL.

Comment: What are the pros and cons of form_post versus query string?

Comment: The URL(query string) option is not recommended, as the URL itself can be caught in log files/browser history... ; also there is a length limit on how long a URL can be, compared to the POST option, that has no size limit.